# Can I still use WMI to manage SQL Server 2005 and 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, wmi

I've seen some articles on how to use [WMI to manage SQL2000](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1559341/Automating-SQL-Server-Management-with-WMI-Part-3.htm) servers (after installing SQLWMI80.msi manually) but I've not seen anything about this for SQL2005 and SQL2008.

Has this been depreciated?  Or is WMI now installed as standard with 2005 and 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes see [SQL Server 2008 Books Online (June 2009)WMI Provider for Configuration Management Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180499.aspx)  this also provides the links to the 2005 version.  But you'll want to use SMO instead.  2008 also has a powershell provider.

Comment: Ho Ho! Another way to do the same thing invented by MS.  Looking at SMO and seeing if it can be incorporated into my "monitoring" architecture, that mostly uses WMI.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred method is to use [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)